# Java program to connect mysql using socket=/opt/zimbra/db/mysql.sock

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I have fetched my mail from gmail account to local zimbra machine and which is stored in mysql database, which run mysql on 7306 port and /opt/zimbra/db/mysql.sock.

Now, I would like to access all those record via java program.

I have used Spring with Java program using zimbra java version 1.7.0_07-b10

Here is configuration in xml file ..

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://172.18.100.117:7306/mboxgroup8?socket=/opt/zimbra/db/mysql.sock"/>
        <property name="username" value="zimbra"/>
        <property name="password" value="Zy"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="60000"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="Select 1"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000"/>
    </bean>
```

When I tried to connect via program, it gives me below error...

```
getMails-  59- Exception in getMails at Manager:org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:182)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.executeWithListResult(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:219)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:266)
    at com.cashEmail.core.dao.MailItemDAOImpl.selectByExampleWithBLOBs(MailItemDAOImpl.java:86)
    at com.cashEmail.manager.CashManager.getMails(CashManager.java:48)
    at com.cashEmail.core.service.CashService.getCashEmail(CashService.java:77)
    at com.cashEmail.resource.CashResource.getEmails(CashResource.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```